# Solve the initial value problem $4\left(\sin(t)\frac{dy}{dt}+\cos(t)y\right)=\cos(t)\sin^3(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, integrating-factor

> Solve the initial value problem
>
> $$4\bigg(\sin(t)\frac{dy}{dt}+\cos(t)y\bigg)=\cos(t)\sin^3(t)$$
>
> for $0<t<\pi$ and $y(\pi/2)=20$.
> Put the problem in standard form.

I've calculated the integrating factor as being $\sin(t)$
I just can't seem to solve $y(t)$.

---

**Edit (After reading your answers):**

Here is the work that I have so far;
I multiplied every term by the integrating factor $p(t)=\sin(t)$
$$\sin(t)\frac{dy}{dt}+\cos(t)y=\frac{1}{4}\cos(t)\sin^3(t)$$

Then took the total differential of the left side;

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\sin(t)y)=\frac{1}{4}\cos(t)\sin^3(t)$$

Then integrated from ($\pi/2\to t$);

$$\sin(t)y(t)-\sin(\pi/2)y(\pi/2)=\frac{1}{16}\sin^4(t)-\frac{1}{16}\sin^4(\pi/2)$$

$$\implies \sin(t)y(t)=20+\frac{1}{16}(\sin^4(t)-1)$$
$$\implies y(t)=\frac{321}{16}\csc(t)+\frac{1}{16}\sin^3(t)$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, if you could tell us more about your own thoughts towards the question, more people will help.

Comment: Howdy! Please refrain from using phrases like "Please help," especially in all caps. It looks kinda bad and you'll be less likely to get good answers.

Comment: Look at the left hand side and see if you can put it in the form $\frac{d f}{dt} $. Once you've done this the next bit should be easy since you will have $\frac{d f(t)}{dt} =$ another function of $t$.

Answer (score 2):

If we put $$z=\sin (t)y $$

the equation becomes

$$\frac {dz}{dt}=\frac {1}{4}\sin^3 (t)\cos (t) $$
$$=\frac {1}{16}\frac {d \sin^4 (t)}{dt} $$

hence by integration,
$$z=\frac {1}{16}\sin^4 (t)+C $$

You can finish.

Comment: I rolled back the edit to the original one, because there is no problem with the suggested substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't share any ideas with us, I don't want to give a full answer to that problem. The key idea is to use a technique called "variation of constants". Try to solve the homogeneous problem (the left hand side equals zero) and solve this using seperation of variables. Keep the constant $C$ variable in $t$. You should end up with something like $$y(t) = -C(t) \, \sin(t).$$ Then, you derive this expression with respect to $t$, which gives you $$\dot{y}(t) = -\dot{C}(t) \, \sin(t) - C(t) \, \cos(t).$$ Using your differential equation on the left hand side, you end up with the condition $$-\dot{C}(t) \, \sin(t) = \frac{1}{4} \, \sin^2(t) \, \cos(t).$$ You will end up with a solution $$y(t) \sim \sin^3(t).$$ Be careful with those calculations, the details of some moduli are left out, maybe you devide by zero and you have to put in the right initial data, but I am sure you can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing the ODE by $4$, one obtains:
$$\sin(t)\cdot y'+\cos(t)\cdot y=\frac{1}{4}\cos(t)\sin^3(t) \tag{1}$$
Now we recall the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule), and apply it in reverse on the LHS. Remember that $(\sin(t))'=\cos(t)$, therefore, we have from $(1)$:
$$\sin(t)\cdot y'+(\sin(t))'\cdot y=\frac{1}{4}\cos(t)\sin^3(t)$$
$$(\sin(t)\cdot y)'=\frac{1}{4}\cos(t)\sin^3(t) \tag{2}$$
Now integrate both sides of $(2)$ with respect to $t$, and you will have your general solution. All that remains to do now is to apply the condition you were given to obtain the particular solution: $y(\pi/2)=20$.

---

**Edit:** You've shown us what you've tried after reading the above. The only mistake is your fraction which I highlighted in red when transitioning between the following step:
$$\sin(t)y(t)=20+\frac{1}{16}(\sin^4(t)-1) \not\Rightarrow y(t)=\color{red}{\frac{321}{16}}\csc(t)+\frac{1}{16}\sin^3(t)$$
Remember that $20-\dfrac{1}{16}\equiv \dfrac{320}{16}-\dfrac{1}{16}\equiv \dfrac{319}{16}$.

Comment: So after integrating, I have; sin(t)*y(t)=20+(1/16)(sin(t)^4-1)

Comment: which gets me to y(t)=(321/16)csc(t)+(1/16)sin(t)^3, and I feel way off on this answer

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be:
$$y(t)=\color{red}{\frac{319}{16}}\csc(t)+\frac{1}{16}\sin^3(t)$$
I think you made an arithmetic mistake, since $20-\frac{1}{16}=\frac{319}{16}$. Apart from that, your solution is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Im new to this site and trying to figure out how to properly respond/comment and I'm at work, so my response time is slow.